# How can X'=MX+B be written as Y'=MX

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

You have a system in the form X'= MX+B, show that it can be written as Y'= MY. M is an n by n constant matrix. B is an n by 1 constant vector. M is non-singular.

I really don't know how to go about this problem and I'm not entirely sure what it's asking.  There is nothing in our book proving anything like this, I've scoured the internet, looked through another Advanced Eng. Math book, tried a few different manipulations myself, but to no avail.  This seems like one of those really simple problems that I've convoluted (pun intended) to the point that I can't even think anymore.

I'm not necessarily looking for the exact answer, just something to point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: I have Advanced Engineering Mathematics by Dean G Duffy and also an unpublished book by my professor.  I tried to integrate both sides, which is probably dumb but I really don't know what's being asked of me here.  It seems to me that they are in the same form already except for the constant vector.

Comment: Rewriting $Y'=MX$ is not very useful here. Looks like a typo. Are you sure it is not $Y'=M\color{red}{Y}$?

Comment: Yes sorry! It is supposed to be MY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Let $Y'=X'-B$. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks!  So I see how that easily becomes X' = MX + B, but I'm not really sure what the purpose of the proof is.  Oh well, I guess that's a separate question.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept this answer using the tick.